# how to validate a Map<String, Object> in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I know I can validate a custom class like stated in

```
 http://hibernate.org/validator/
```

However, now I have a parameter which has a type of Map. how can I validate that parameter? After all, I cannot go to the HashMap source code and add those annotations.

I came across an article here

```
http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator
```

My question is, after I make the custom validator, how can I make hibernate know this validator is used to validate the Map variable in my method?

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear if you're trying to validate the objects or want to actually validate the map itself, like check the string keys against the object values.  Actual code may help :)

Comment: I just want to validate the values in the map.

Comment: Then you can just mark the property with @Valid and it will cascade into the values.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. For example, one of the key value pairs in the map is <String, String>, and I want to validate the length of the String to be in range, how can I do this? I just don't know how to add the constraints.

Comment: On that 2nd link they show you how to make cusom validators. http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator#highlighter_957126